# Filtering в maven-resources-plugin работает не во всех местах

Tags: java, maven, docker

Пытаюсь автоматизировать процесс сборки приложения сразу в Docker образ. Для того чтобы переместить и добавить properties в Dockerfile использую плагин maven-resources-plugin. Все бы ничего, но в некоторых местах он просто не воспринимает переменные, оставляя их как @some.properrty@, причем в одном месте он заменяет, в а другом, туже property - нет.

> ...
>   LABEL component="@project.shortname@" - работает
>   ...
>   ENV APP @project.shortname@.jar - нет

Может, кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема разрешилась. Все дело было в email, который также содержит '@'.